# Setting textbox encoding in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, textbox

When I try to get some text from file and display it in textbox it is okay until I want to write Czech characters (e. g. čšž). They show up like: `Moj� nejv�t�� z�libou je �e�en� koresponden�n�ch semin���`

Should I set encoding to loaded text just before I assign it to textBox1.text or it is possible to change encoding of textBox1.Text itself?

I use following code:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to force the encoding (the machine default should be OK, if you don't know the correct one):

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(file,Encoding.Default);
```

Anyway, being Czech I guess your current default encoding is "Western European (Windows)" (you can get it also doing `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`)

That is also the one on my pc (I have an Italian version of Win7).

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN for ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

> This method attempts to automatically
>   detect the encoding of a file based on
>   the presence of byte order marks.
>   Encoding formats UTF-8 and UTF-32
>   (both big-endian and little-endian)
>   can be detected.
>
> Use the ReadAllText(String, Encoding)
>   method overload when reading files
>   that might contain imported text,
>   because unrecognized characters may
>   not be read correctly.

Try using the other overload to explicitly specify the Encoding since automatic detection is not working in your case, something like

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8);
```